# How to prove that $V_n$ is a seq in this case .

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following:

$V_n = U_n - \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is an unknown real value .

I also know that : $$U_0 = 7/2$$ $$U_{n+1} = \frac{1}{5} U_n + 2$$

I need to find the value of $\alpha$ in order for $V_n$ to be a geometric sequance, which mean that I need to compute the following :

$$\frac{V_{n+1}}{V_n}$$ to find ***Q*** which should be a const .

That's all what I have as Info to solve this problem, but I can't get anywhere from here.

Comment: I think you typed it wrong. Did you mean $U_{n+1} = \frac{1}{5}U_n+2$?

Comment: Yesss, I've changed the original post .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U_{n+1}-\frac{5}{2}=\frac{1}{5}(U_n-\frac{5}{2})$

Classic trick for arithmetico-geometric series.

(Solve $U_{n+1}-\alpha = \frac{1}{5}(U_n-\alpha)$)

Comment: You mean $\frac{7}{2}$ or  $\frac{5}{2}$ ?

Comment: $\frac{5}{2}$. How do you get $\frac{7}{2}$?